# How to align bold,italic and underline in wp-admin?

Tags: pages, wp-admin, css

When Im in wp-admin and editing a page and whant to make underline, bold and italic it dont appear on the site. I understand therese something i have to define in the css or thru wp-admin ?

NOTE: I want the user to easly edit and i know how to do it thru css. But what I want is to edit thru the edit-page.

Comment: Can you post the code displaying the content on the frontend, if you have links leading their too that would be a great help. As it currently stands your question simply doesn't have enough information to give an answer to

Comment: Thanks but its solved now. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is editor mode specific, then make a CSS file named: `editor-style.css` and then add the following code into `functions.php` within PHP tags:

```
// CUSTOM EDITOR STYLES
// This theme styles the visual editor with editor-style.css to match the theme style.
add_editor_style();
```

Now put some CSS code to match the site's CSS into the editor.

Answer (score 0):

Found the soulution.

It was in the Css-reset

font: inherit; should be removed.

Then it will apply in wp-admin.